# Highcharts: Errorbar for series, only for the y-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot something with Highcharts, which works pretty well. As soon as I try to include some errorbars for the y-values, nothing works anymore.
My code I use so far looks like this:

```
$(function () { 
        my_data = {{p_data}}
        my_error = {{p_error}}
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('plot', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Test plot '
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'logarithmic',
                title: {
                    text: 'x-axis'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'logarithmic',
                title: {
                    text: 'y-axis'
                }
            },                      
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Test data',
                data: my_data } 
                ,{ 
                name: 'Test Error',
                type: 'errorbar',
                data: my_error }
                ]
        });
    });
```

Whereas I get my data and error from a form, and they look like this:

```
p_data = [[1, 1.1], [2, 2.3], ... [122, 123]]
p_error = [[1, 0.9, 1.3], [2, 2.1, 2.5], ... [122, 122.8,123.2]]
```

As you can see I only want my errorbars to effect the y-Values, and here I give the down and upper limit.
Why does this not work?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Works for me with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/tkzg09kh/

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in console? Maybe you forgot to include highcharts-more script? Also, why are you not using `p_data` and `p_error` directly? I placed your code in JSFiddle, did the necessary corrections and it works like a charm. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjhfgh0u/.

Comment: @ewolden Included the original data here: http://jsfiddle.net/2nm3j7L3/ You can see as soon as I include the error bars, the plot is disappearing. When you delete the error bars, the data is displayed properly.

Comment: If you look in console, you will see that you have this error message: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/10. Removing all the 0 values in the errorbar data, it works, and looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2nm3j7L3/1/

Comment: @nieka It is because type of both, x and y axis is logarithmic and when that is the case, you cannot plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis (see the error #10 in console). Get rid of logarithmic type of axes or change data to not to crossing 0 values on yAxis.

Comment: @ewolden  thanks ! that's it. Due to the bigger idea behind this plot I will need the logarithmic scale. Did you write a function to replace the zero values with a really small number instead? EDIT: sry. I missed the part where you explained that you kicked the data, where the values are 0!

Comment: @nieka No function, I just flat out removed them. Since you have the X value anyway, there is presumably no need to have them there. Depending on how you get that data and how dynamic it is, I would either just check for zero value on export and not export those lines, or make a function as you say that remove them. It is obviously possible to make a function that generates really small numbers, but I don't see any advantage in that.